# Android Lazy Loading working on emulator, not in device

Tags: android, android-emulator, lazy-loading

I found an example of lazy loading, and I believe I have implemented it properly. It works properly in an emulator, but when I run the same code on my device, it does not work. It does not download the images, and I have checked to confirm that the device is connected to the internet.

I am not sure why my code is working only on an emulator so I created a new AVD hoping to delete the cache. On my new AVD it was working properly as before, but when I tried I my device it worked at first but failed after only two tries. My code still does not download the images.

Is there a common reason why it could be running in AVD but not on my device?

Comment: Im sry man'''I don't get you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Below Link for that, it is work for me.

[Lazy Loading Listview](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)